# Fortify XML External Entities (XXE)

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling, fortify, xxe

I got a XML External Entity Injection security warn of line 4 in fortify report. Have no idea how to fix it. I'm quite new to SOAP,JAXB, and Marshaller.

```
1    private TargetObject convert( ResponseEntity<String> response ) throws JAXBException{

2       JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( TargetObject.class );

3       Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

4       StringReader reader = new StringReader( Objects.requireNonNull( response.getBody() ) );

5       TargetObject targetObject = (ArrayOfOrderList) unmarshaller.unmarshal( reader );

6       return targetObject;

7    }
```

line 4 (XML External Entity Injection) High
Issue Details
Kingdom: Input Validation and Representation
Scan Engine: SCA (Semantic)
Sink Details
Sink: unmarshal()

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read : [OWASP XXE Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). this will get you the solution